# C pointer arithmetic snippet

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, nested-loops

I have a program that I'm trying to decode. It is translated to C from another language ([whose name is not spoken here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck)), and as I want to understand how it works, I am slowly rewriting the code and simplifying it to use all the nice logical constructs C has to offer.

The following little bit keeps popping up in my code, with varying values of `X` and `Y`:

```
ptr[X]--;
while(ptr[X])
  {
    ptr[X]--;
    ptr += Y;
  }
```

`ptr` is of type `char *`, and I can't really make assumptions about the state of the array at any point because it's pretty deeply embedded in loops and dependent on input and output. I can successfully "simplify" that to:

```
for(ptr[X]--; ptr[X]; ptr[X]--, ptr += Y);
```

But that's just awful. Ever so slightly better is:

```
for(ptr[X]--; ptr[X]; ptr += Y) ptr[X]--;
```

I want to know if anyone can come up with a better simplification of the above code, I would greatly appreciate it. This occurs in no less than five places, and is impairing my ability to simplify and understand the flow control, so if anyone can provide a more consise/readable version, that would be awesome. If anyone can just offer any sort of fancy insight into that code, that would be awesome too, although I basically understand what it does.

Insight into the code for a specific `X` and/or `Y` can also help. `Y` tends to be between -2 and 2, and `X` is usually 1, for what its worth.

Comment: Could someone explain to me the use for something remotely real of the "language not discussed here"

Comment: Hm, perhaps an exercise in pointer manipulation?

Comment: @Tom - Amusement, entertainment? I wrote an interpreter for it to teach myself C, and that was kind of useful.

Comment: @Chris. I was only asking. It hasn't been that long since i first read about it, and always wondered its use. Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: Fair enough. If I can add some interesting points, a basic `cat` utility in it is as simple as ",[.,]". This specific program is actually a bf interpreter written in bf, and I want to understand how it works because it's the only interpreter I can imagine that wouldn't be written with recursion (and I know how to write one with recursion already).

Comment: I would love to see more of the surrounding code so I can offer some insight into why this code does what it does. If ptr was actually a char ** (or char *[]) it would make more sense, i.e searching for null in several strings. As it is, it is more like some sort of ROT-Y encryption method, reducing character values in a string towards NULL for one reason or another.

Comment: @Tom Leys - As someone looking at the surrounding code, you don't want to see it. I've been simplifying the logic for hours and it still has if()s and while()s nested at least eight levels deep, and probably more. If you really want to see the code I have thus far in context, I can post it on some pastebin, but I fear it may take a while to fully work out how it works. I can tell you what it does, but how it works is what I'm working on finding out right now.

Answer (score 8):

`ptr[X]` is equivalent to `*(ptr + X)`, so we can rewrite it as follows:

```
for((*(ptr + X))--; *(ptr + X); (*(ptr + X))--, ptr += Y);
```

Now there's a lot of redundancy here, so we can simplify this to:

```
char *ptr_plus_x = ptr + X;
for((*ptr_plus_x)--; *ptr_plus_x; (*ptr_plus_x)--, ptr_plus_x += Y);
```

Then we can get rid of `ptr_plus_x` entirely:

```
ptr += X;
for((*ptr)--; *ptr; (*ptr)--, ptr += Y);
```

In English, we visit the memory locations at offsets X, X+Y, X+2Y, X+3Y, ..., decrementing each memory location, until we find a memory location that is 0.  But, the test for 0 always occurs after the decrement, so we're really looking for the first memory location in that sequence with a value of 1.  Once we find that, we decrement it to 0 and quit.

If Y is 1, then we decrement a string of consecutive memory locations going forwards, up to and including the first 1.  If Y is -1, the same thing happens, but searching backwards from offset X.  If Y is 0, an infinite loop occurs.  If Y is any other value, the search pattern skips various entries.

It's not a very intuitive function, so I can see why you're confused.

Comment: Either it's more confusing than either of us think, or it's just hard to look at out of context. This version gives me a bus error. I thought I would correct it by adding ptr -= X at the end of the for() loop, and this removes the bus error, but doesn't work (produces no output).

Comment: I would suggest to use pre decrement instead of post decrement and also to add the instruction ptr -= X after the loop instruction to restore exactly the ptr variable to exactly the same state as in the original code. Unless it is not needed of course.

Comment: Not an infinite loop if Y=0. Just makes the current location 0 (or underflows), without moving back or forth.

Answer (score 3):

I'll throw in:

```
ptr[X]--
while (ptr[X]--) ptr+=Y;
```

first evaluate, then decrement (for while condition, that is)

Edit: OK, i'll hate myself in the morning. Goto's are ok at this level, right?

```
dec:  ptr[x]--
      while (ptr[X]){
           ptr+=Y;
           goto dec;
      }
```

(i honestly dont know whether to leave this or not.)

EDIT2: so, how about this one? (tcc didn't complain)

```
 while (ptr[X]--?ptr[X]--,ptr+=Y:0){}
```

EDIT 2 1/2;

```
  //longshot
  while (ptr[X]--?ptr[X]--,ptr+=Y, ptr[X]:0){}
```

If all else fails..

EDIT3: Last one for tonight.

```
while (ptr[X]--?ptr[X]--,ptr+=Y:0){
      if (!ptr[X]) break;
 }//good luck with this, it has been very amusing.
```

Comment: This was one of the first things I tried, but it gives me a bus error. For what it's worth, adding `ptr[X]++` at the end DOES work, so it's just an off-by-one error.

Comment: Again, no, the post condition is wrong since you subtract too much from the final ptr[X].

Comment: Re: goto: Leave it. It doesn't quite work (needs an extra ptr[X]-- at the beginning), but is highly amusing.

Comment: The new one produces a bus error, as well as the "warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect" from GCC. Which is odd, because I think it should have some effect.

Comment: I was hoping that ternary operator would end the debate.

Comment: when doing a,b the return value of the whole expression is the return value of b. I think its too late alredy.

Comment: Now the ternary one doesn't produce a bus error, but instead loops infinitely. I think there's too much --ing in the ternary solution.

Comment: Maybe the array is to large? I've run some dummy tests with gcc (no "languange not discussed here") and it ends.

Comment: You are right, the -- before the ? is ruining it when the loop loops.

Answer (score 2):

The website for it-which-shall-not-be-named states:

```
The semantics of the it-which-shall-not-be-named states commands can also
be succinctly expressed in terms of C, as follows (assuming that p has 
been previously defined as a char*):

>   becomes     ++p;
<   becomes     --p;
+   becomes     ++*p;
-   becomes     --*p;
.   becomes     putchar(*p);
,   becomes     *p = getchar();
[   becomes     while (*p) {
]   becomes     }
```

So it seems like it should be fairly easy to convert it over to C.

**EDIT:** [Here is the Hello World BF converted to C++.](http://pastebin.com/f7a469805)

Comment: I'm past that step. I used an optimized version of that same basic chart, so ++++ got translated to *p += 4;. Now I'm trying to reduce the code logic down to something more usable.

Comment: Can you post the piece of BF that is getting translated into that loop?

Comment: It would be something like ">X-[->Y]<X", but change X and Y to X or Y number of >s or <s. "-[-<]" (straight from the source), where X is 0. (X has changed from the original translation because I've been messing with the code, but I verify that the simplified code does what it's supposed to, so it should all be functionally equivalent.)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple as is, already.  Instead of trying to write less statements, I would rather try to grasp the intent and add some comment.

An example of 'a' meaning of the snippet: decrease all elements of a column (X) of a matrix of Y columns.  You would need that to draw a vertical line of +'ses, for instance, in a language that has no direct assignment.

You could clarify this meaning by showing the indices directly:

```
// set elements of column to cGoal
for( int decrementsToGoal = cGoal; decrementsToGoal != 0; --decrementsToGoal ) {
    // decrease all elements of column X
    for( int row = cMaxRows; M[ row*matrixsizeY + columnX ]; --row ) {
        --M[ row*matrixsizeY + columnX ];
    }
}
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I don't necessarily want to reduce the number of statements, I just want to simplify the logic. In particular, I'm having problems with the fact that the loop affects both the pointer an the pointee, which is keeping me from simplifying it like I have done with other parts of the code.

Comment: I think xtofl might have got that idea from my statements. I was having fun :)

Comment: @Tom: Your code is almost as unreadable as a ... perl script :P